# Spring boot addInterceptors not being called in Websphere application server

Tags: java, spring, websphere

I have a Spring Boot app using SpringWS. Inside of the WsConfigurerAdapter I am overriding addInterceptors in order to add logging/authentication/validation/etc.

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
@EnableWs
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

    ...

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors) {
        EnvironmentSettings environment = getEnvironmentSettings();

        interceptors.add(getLogSetupInterceptor());
        interceptors.add(getAuthenticationInterceptor());
        interceptors.add(getServerLoggingInterceptor());
        interceptors.add(getAuthorizationInterceptor());
        ServerPayloadValidatingInterceptor validatingInterceptor = new ServerPayloadValidatingInterceptor();
        validatingInterceptor.setValidateRequest(environment.isValidateSoapRequest());
        validatingInterceptor.setValidateResponse(environment.isValidateSoapResponse());
        validatingInterceptor.setXsdSchema( xsdSchema());
        interceptors.add(validatingInterceptor);
    }
}
```

What is strange is that when run locally, all of these interceptors are being added and run for every request just fine. However, when I deploy the application as a .war to WAS, this one method is not being run. I even added logging statements and I can tell that it's this method that's getting skipped over instead of the interceptors themselves. Does anybody know something about spring boot .war files that I don't?

Also, here is my Application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer  {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I did wrong. It turns out I was creating a servlet mapping in both my WebServiceConfig and my web.xml both at /*.